Pycharm isn't showing Camera window
I want to write python code on my PC and run it on my raspberry PI 5,
I don't want to use Pi to write code in it.
I was running Remote development from Pycharm IDE on my PC.

I was trying to run basic script using Picamera2; basically that script shows preview of Arducam camera module.
Script is like below :
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview

picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)

preview_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(preview_config)

picam2.start()
time.sleep(5)

I Want to see preview window on my PC (if that's possible)
But Result shows error:

unable to display!!
need suggestions
this script was supposed to show camera preview of Arducam camera module;
If i run this script in PI, camera preview shows as it supposed to, but if i run this from my PC through Pycharm remote development It shows error.

How is this "Remote development" set up, and should graphical applications on the Pi be expected to show up locally? Why?

not just locally i want to see it's expected result anywhere anyhow. I think I missed to elaborate my query earlier, so I edited my Query above

@fwiz. One problem is update Pycharrm
